# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'location')

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, router

I wrote this code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import AboutPage from './pages/aboutPage'

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router>
    <Route path='/' component={ App }/>
    <Route path='/about' component={ AboutPage }/>
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Why doesn't it work? I'm getting this error:[image]

How can I fix it? React v17.0.2, React-router v5.2.1, React-router-dom v6.0.1

Comment: Show us the actual `Router.js`

Comment: As the error is saying itself, error is coming from 'Router.js' file where the property 'history' value is not defined at the point where it is trying to read 'location' value.

Comment: @k-wasilewski 
https://jsfiddle.net/mustmusk/kcpmxzaw/

Answer (score 4):

A `Route` is only ever to be used as the child of `Routes` element, never rendered directly. So just wrap your `<Route>` in a `<Routes>`

```
<Router>
  <Routes>
    <Route path='/' component={ App }/>
    <Route path='/about' component={ AboutPage }/>
  </Routes>
</Router>
```

Comment: Did it. No results.

Comment: Router just can't find current location and I don't know why and how to fix it

Comment: Are you using "React router v5" and "react-router-dom v6" at the same project?!

Answer (score 2):

In my case to fix that issue, it was the `react-router-dom` that wasn't match the `react-router` package.

For example:

```
    "react-router": "^5.3.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.3",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.3",
```

Answer (score -1):

Wrap your component (the one where you're using `props.location`) with the `withRouter` to inject the former:

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
...
}

export default withRouter(MyComponent);
```

Comment: "Attempted import error: 'withRouter' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'."